# How to highlight embedded code block on github?

Tags: github, markdown

Documentation clearly states that code block inside sentence marked using `backticks`.

```Language_Name_Here
For for multi-line block we can use triple backticks

```

But how I can specify language name for embedded block of code? Like `<XmlNode Prop="Value" />`? I just want to prettify my readme.md to look like this inside sentence:

```xml
<XmlNode Prop="Value" />
```

Looks like the same question related to stackowerflow itself. "language-all" comment is not working for embedded code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to me that this is possible. The [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#code-fence) refers to this as an **info string** for the **code fence** (aka **fenced code block**). The [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#code-spans) for **code spans** (inline code like you are asking about) does not support info strings.